# A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

What kind of errors is this ?

I am getting this error while doing the update of my cache with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error :

```
Err https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages               
  gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

Image for reference : [image]

Comment: Are you using some sort of proxy? Did the problem start when you obtained a new internet provider, router, modem, or other network equipment?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ NO , i am collapsed with my Ubuntu and got a fresh installation and this is the first update I'm doing

Comment: Is it using the same CD as your previous installation?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ No its a different ISO .

Comment: I think it may be a different version of `gnutls`. I honestly don't know what to do now.