# Getting an error while installing calculator lens

Tags: software-installation, lenses, calculator

This is the error I get every time I try installing calculator lens

```
yash@yash-desktop:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
[sudo] password for yash: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for yash: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 128, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.')
yash@yash-desktop:~$
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Where did you find that ppa? This "A TLS packet with unexpected length was received." on google seems to show up when older PPA's are used in newer Ubuntu versions. Same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211759/a-tls-packet-with-unexpected-length-was-received

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://iloveubuntu.net/unity-utilities-lens-adds-calculator-based-features-unity)? It is from 2011, so could be for versions old as Ubuntu 10...

Comment: It appears to to have been solved for 13.04 [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143808) - *It may add other scopes as well* - But if it works for you I'll add a copy as an answer... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing smart scopes (from 13.10). Here's how:

First, you want to add the repository.
Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Copy/Paste, or type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-unity/experimental-certified
```

Then update...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Last, upgrade the scopes already installed, and install a bunch of new ones.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

<sub>*NOTE::"for the last command above, make sure no packages are removed except for the `unity-lens-shopping`. If the command tries to remove more packages, it means something is broken on your system and you need to fix it so do not proceed with the installation!"*</sub>

So the system doesn't overwrite the newly installed scopes if 13.04 gets new scopes, type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-experimental-certified
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

... and you're done.

When you search in Dash, you'll have a bunch of new scopes, calculator being one of them. You may have to click <kbd>Filter results</kbd> on the right and activate calculator.

---

<sub>'Borrowed' from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143808)</sub>